# FOP Code for pdf generation: table cells are rendered weird

Tags: apache-fop

I currently use FOP Code to generate .pdf files. I need to dynamically generate a table based on the user input. In CMS `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`are defined to be the following:

td:

```
<fo:table-cell padding-top="0pt" padding-left="5.4pt" padding-bottom="0pt" padding-right="5.4pt"  border-left-style="solid" border-right-style="solid"  border-left-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-right-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-left-width="0.0pt" border-right-width="0.0pt" border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-style="solid" border-top-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-bottom-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-top-width="0.0pt" border-bottom-width="0.0pt">
<fo:block font-family="$CMS_VALUE(mainFontFamily)$" color="$CMS_VALUE(mainFontColor)$" font-size="$CMS_VALUE(fontSize)$pt" language="DE" text-align="left">
    <fo:inline font-weight="normal" font-size="$CMS_VALUE(fontSize)$pt">
    <fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
          $CMS_VALUE(#content)$
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

table:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" font-family="$CMS_VALUE(mainFontFamily)$" color="$CMS_VALUE(mainFontColor)$" start-indent="0pt" border-style="solid"  border-top-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-top-width="0.0pt" border-left-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-left-width="0.0pt" border-bottom-color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-bottom-width="0.0pt" border-right color="$CMS_VALUE(borderColor)$" border-right-width="0.0pt">

$CMS_FOR(col,[1..#table.cols])$
    <fo:table-column column-number="$CMS_VALUE(col)$" column-width="$CMS_VALUE(100.0/#table.cols)$%"/>
$CMS_END_FOR$       

<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" end-indent="0pt">
    $CMS_VALUE(#content)$
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

tr:

```
<fo:table-row>
$CMS_VALUE(#content)$
</fo:table-row>
```

This however results in a table that is very weirdly formatted (see attached image). I added red borders around a table cell to make it more clear. The big cell in the middle is actually ONE cell and should not have that huge gap within the text after the 3rd row (i just typed in some dummy text...).

Why does this happen and how can i fix it?

I played around with `<fo:leader/>`, `<line-height>` and some other stuff, but nothing of those seem to be the cause of those "split up" cells.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please attach the fo table producing the output depicted in the image; without that it's impossible to see precisely what is going on.

Comment: @Ifurini: Problem is: How am i going to get that code? I assume you want the generated FOP code. The CMS itself only generates the pdf, there is no intermediate step for me to grab the generated fop code..